# How to convert a Python project to using virtualenv when dependencies are a mess?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pip, dependency-management

I've used Python for a few years, but it has never been my primary language, and I've never used it for projects where I needed to worry much about dependencies.

The time has come when I need to use `virtualenv`. Installing it seems easy enough, but I'm trying to understand a logical way to develop the list of dependencies being used by my current project.

If I try `pip freeze -l` I find over 100 dependencies, most of which are not used my this project.

Is there an easy way to discover which of the libraries (along with versions) installed on my machine are used by this project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any good way to do this, unfortunately. Generally when I'm faced with this kind of situation, I'll use `pip freeze` to get the versions of all the packages installed on my system, then just start guessing and checking which ones are needed for the project.

For example, if I know my project needs Django, I'll figure out which version of Django is listed by `pip freeze`, add that to the project's `requirements.txt` file, install that version of Django into the virtualenv, then try to run the project and see what crashes.

You could also do a sanity check to make sure that you haven't missed anything by running something like:

```
egrep -h -R --include='*.py' '^(import|from) ' myproject/ | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -u
```

And double checking that all the non-standard-library packages are installed.

Note, though, that this won't consider packages which aren't explicitly imported…